# How do I download file from public folder in React using Express

Tags: reactjs, express

I'm using Reactjs for client side and Express for server code.

I want to download a file located in the `public/uploads` folder called `game.zip`

This is my React component with download button.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';

class FileDownload extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {  }
    }
    render () {
        return ( 
            <Fragment>
                <div className="row">
                     <div className="container col-3">
                     <form method="GET" action="/download">
                        <input
                            type='submit'
                            value='Download'
                            className='btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4'
                        />
                        </form>

                    </div>
                </div>
                    
            </Fragment>
         );
    }
}
 
export default FileDownload;
```

This is my Express route inside server.js file.

```
app.get('/download', function(req, res){
    const file = `${__dirname}/client/public/uploads/game.zip`;
    res.download(file); // Set disposition and send it.
  });
```

This solution doesn't work, the express route isn't called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need the form at all, try something like this instead:

```
<Fragment>
  <div className="row">
    <a 
      href="http://localhost:5000/download"
      target="_blank" 
      className="container col-3"
    >
      <button className='btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4'/>
    </a>
  </div>
</Fragment>
```

In the `href` attribute I assume you have your server listening on port 5000, you may change it to point to your server.

Also try the behavior without the `target` attribute, you might not need it

Comment: It didn't change the behaviour. The express app.get route is still not called.

Comment: Hmm so this is something about how you serve your client files, do you have a separated server for the client? In that case, the `href` should be `href="http://localhost:3000/download"` (assuming that your server port is 3000)

Comment: React is running on port 3000 and Express listen on port 5000.

Comment: What is the correct way of implementing it?